Vue problems with Github page route with params
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: ()=> import('@/components/Home/Home.vue')},  
  { path: '/:marca/cars', component: ()=> import('@/components/Cars/Cars.vue')},  
];

const BASE_URL = '/Forza3API1/';

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(BASE_URL), 
  routes
});

export default router;

Route => Forza3API1/Abarth%20/cars
The other route works fine, the problem is this. Github page give me 404 but in local work
fine.
I don't know why?

I answered a similar answer here: How would I make Vue Router work with GitHub Pages?
TLDR is the fact that it can be very complex to setup that on Github pages. I honestly did not achieved something functional. Hence I recommend using any other free hosting platform like Netlify
, Vercel, Cloudflare, Digital Ocean etc etc...
You really don't have any benefits using Github pages. The deployment workflow is not even that easy for 2024.

Thanks ... i will try it a bit more but atleast i have the session storage as last resource...

@nepko session storage? How is it related?

sorry for the waiting. [I have a table with cars], [User wants to see a car's info] ,
[Click in SHOW ],[with a function save the id of the car in the session storage],
[redirect user to  Forza3API1/cars] , [here, I load the id in the storage]
[load the car info and show it]

@nepko hm okay? I am not sure how it is related to the current question you asked. Having a given workflow is cool and all but having a 404 is quite a different issue.
